# Using apklibs as maven dependecies

Tags: java, android, maven, svn

I am using Android Studio 0.4.5 and I am trying to import a maven project.

Everything works fine , I can build/deploy the app on device without any problems.

What I do not understand is why the apklibs which I have defined in my pom(and which can be found in my m2 repo) such as actionsherlockbar , androidFilePicker are not loaded from the maven repo as external libraries.

Instead , a gen-external-apk-libs folder is created inside the workspace with the source code for each of them.

I don t want to add this folder to subversion and I want those apklibs to be loaded as maven dependencies from the repo.

Is there any solution for this?

Here is how i have my actionBarSherlock defined:
          `<dependency>
                <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
                <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.0</version>
                <type>apklib</type>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
                    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
                  </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>`